# Generating random values and keeping track of their sum

Tags: php, random, for-loop

I have more than 200 entries in a database table and I would like to generate a random value for each entry, but in the end, the sum of entries values must equal 100. Is it possible to do this using a for loop and rand() in PHP?

Comment: How can the sum be less then the total number of rows, are you allowing Zero values? Also did you have a range for each row random value, as if you allow 0-100, the first row may get 100 and the remaining rows zeroed out... Coud you allude to why or what you need this random number for...

Comment: yes just make sure your random number is an integer >= 1

Comment: You could count all the values and then divide that number by 100. Then randomize a value between 0.1 and that result and assign to each entry. The sum will always be below 100. You do understand that your numbers will be floats (i.e. not integers)?

Comment: You need to elaborate more on what exactly you want, because as it stands your question is a little bit ridiculous. Right now, with 200 rows and a requirement that the sum be less than 100 you can only reliably get away with `(float)(rand()/getrandmax())*0.5;` or in mySQL `RAND() * 0.5`.

Comment: @silkfire, of course, the numbers will be floats.

Comment: @Sammitch: imagine that there are 200 tv stations and you have to generate a random number for each channel audience. In the end, the sum of each channel audience must be 100%.

Comment: @Psyche The sum will NOT be 100. It will be below 100, but the chances to become exactly 100 are extremely slim.

Comment: you say not greater than 100 in one place and must equal 100 in another, so which is it?

Comment: @Dagon, must equal 100.

Comment: It can't equal === 100, that's like impossible :D. It's like throwing a glass onto the ground and then assembling all the pieces into an exact copy of the unbroken glass. Just. Not. Physically. Possible.

Comment: if you wait long enough, entropy will make *everything* equal.

Comment: Check my answer demo is here-> http://codepad.viper-7.com/KrZnXW

Comment: @Robert The sum must 100, not 200, according to OP's requirements.

Comment: I've changed 1 variable which is $max now sum is 100. http://codepad.viper-7.com/Y7XZmR

Comment: Well, based on your TV comment above, can't you just assign each row a random number, then that row's 'channel audience' would be row's number/ sum of all row numbers? Seems much simpler to handle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply normalize a set of numbers, like:

```
$numbers = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 200; $i += 1) {
  $numbers[] = rand();
}

$sum = array_sum($numbers);

// divide $sum by the target sum, to have an instant result, e.g.:
// $sum = array_sum($numbers) / 100;
// $sum = array_sum($numbers) / 42;
// ...

$numbers = array_map(function ($n) use($sum) {
  return $n / $sum;
}, $numbers);

print_r($numbers);
print_r(array_sum($numbers)); // ~ 1
```

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/RDOIvX

Comment: I admit this would be neater than what I suggested.

Comment: @Yoshi, but how about making that sum 100 and not ~ 1? :)

Comment: @Psyche just multiply each value by 100 (or whatever the target sum should be) after normalizing.

Comment: @Psyche How about multiplying by 100? =)

Comment: @Psyche ... or divide `$sum` by the target sum. It's really up to you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The solution for your problem is to rand number from 0 to 200 then put in array, then sum the values and divide it by 200 after that. Loop through elements and divide every element by result of previous equatation it will give you the answer

```
$sum = 0;
$max = 100; //max value to be sumed
$nr_of_records = 200; // number of records that should sum to $max
$arr = array();
for($i=0;$i<$nr_of_records;++$i)
{
   $arr[$i] = rand(0,$max);
}

$div = array_sum($arr) / $max;


for($i=0;$i<$nr_of_records;++$i)
{
  $arr[$i] /= $div;
  echo $arr[$i].'<br>';
}

echo array_sum($arr);
```

[Created living example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Y7XZmR)

Comment: Well, the sum must be 100, not 200, even though there are 200 elements.

Answer (score 1):

How exact has the 100 to be? Just curious, because all hints end at using floating point values, which tend to be inacurate.

I'd propose using fractions... lets say 10000 fractions, each count 1/100 point (10000 * 1/100 = 100 points). Distribute 10000 points to 200 elements, using integers - and be absolutely sure, that the sum of all integers divided by 10000 is 100. There is no need for floats, just think around the corner...

Answer (score 1):

Do a little over/under:

```
$size = 200;
$sum = 100;
$places = 3;

$base = round($sum/$size, $places);

$values = array_fill(0, $size, $base);

for($i=0; $i<$size; $i+=2) {
    $diff = round((rand()/getrandmax()) * $base, $places);
    $values[$i]   += $diff;
    $values[$i+1] -= $diff;
}

//optional: array_shuffle($values);

$sum = 0;

foreach($values as $item) {
    printf("%0.3f ", $item);
    $sum += $item;
}

echo $sum;
```

Output:

> 0.650 0.350 0.649 0.351 0.911 0.089 0.678 0.322 0.566 0.434 0.563 0.437 0.933 0.067 0.505 0.495 0.503 0.497 0.752 0.248 0.957 0.043 0.856 0.144 0.977 0.023 0.863 0.137 0.766 0.234 0.653 0.347 0.770 0.230 0.888 0.112 0.637 0.363 0.716 0.284 0.891 0.109 0.549 0.451 0.629 0.371 0.501 0.499 0.652 0.348 0.729 0.271 0.957 0.043 0.769 0.231 0.767 0.233 0.513 0.487 0.647 0.353 0.612 0.388 0.509 0.491 0.925 0.075 0.797 0.203 0.799 0.201 0.588 0.412 0.788 0.212 0.693 0.307 0.688 0.312 0.847 0.153 0.903 0.097 0.843 0.157 0.801 0.199 0.538 0.462 0.954 0.046 0.541 0.459 0.893 0.107 0.592 0.408 0.913 0.087 0.711 0.289 0.679 0.321 0.816 0.184 0.781 0.219 0.632 0.368 0.839 0.161 0.568 0.432 0.914 0.086 0.991 0.009 0.979 0.021 0.666 0.334 0.678 0.322 0.705 0.295 0.683 0.317 0.869 0.131 0.837 0.163 0.792 0.208 0.618 0.382 0.606 0.394 0.574 0.426 0.927 0.073 0.661 0.339 0.986 0.014 0.759 0.241 0.547 0.453 0.804 0.196 0.681 0.319 0.960 0.040 0.708 0.292 0.558 0.442 0.605 0.395 0.986 0.014 0.621 0.379 0.992 0.008 0.622 0.378 0.937 0.063 0.884 0.116 0.840 0.160 0.607 0.393 0.765 0.235 0.632 0.368 0.898 0.102 0.946 0.054 0.794 0.206 0.561 0.439 0.801 0.199 0.770 0.230 0.843 0.157 0.681 0.319 0.794 0.206 100

The rounding gets a bit squiffy if you're not using nice numbers like 100 and 200, but never more than 0.1 off.

Comment: Nice trick! Not likely in this usecase, but in cryptography, any correlation between the numbers can have a negative impact.

Comment: @Szocske you could always run a few hundred/thousand iterations including the shuffle, but I would wager that having X numbers that add up to Y are inherently useless in crypto no matter how random they are. :P

Answer (score -2):

Original question yesterday had exactly 200 entries and the sum "not greater than 100".
My original answer from yesterday:

> Use random numbers not greater than 0.5 to be sure.
>
> Alternatively, depending on how "random" those numbers need to be (how
>   much correlation is allowed), you could keep a running total, and if
>   it gets disproportionately high, you can mix in a bunch of smaller
>   values.

Edit:

Way to go changing the question, making me look stupid and get downvoted.

To get the exact sum you have to normalize, and better use exact fractions instead of floats to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: this wont result in the sum equalling 100

Comment: @Dragon: that's not what the question was yesterday.